# Nested router not rendering components correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having a weird bug with nested routes in react-router that I'm struggling to fix.

I have two components where I have multiple routes in them. One is a settings component and the other is a profile component. In my settings component things work perfectly fine.

I have three files in my component folder (index.js, editprofile.js, and password.js). I import the components in my index file. Then render them like this.

```
index.js // settings component
...html that renders across all routes
<Route path="/account/settings" exact component={EditProfile} />
<Route path="/account/settings/password" component={Password} />
```

This works as planned. On /account/settings the edit profile component renders and when I link to /account/settings/password the password component appears and the edit profile component is gone.

Now the bug I have is when I try to do the same exact thing in my profile component. I have similar file structure in my profile component (index.js, timeline.js, followers.js, following.js...). I import them into my index.js and render them in the component like this.

```
index.js // profile component
...html that renders across all routes
<Route path="/:username" exact component={Timeline} />
<Route path="/:username/followers" component={Followers} />
...other <Route />'s
```

This loads the Timeline component correctly but when I link to any other routes it loads a blank page. As an alternative I tried to edit the path like below:

```
<Route path={{pathname: '/' + this.props.user.Username}} exact component={Timeline} />
<Route path={{pathname: '/' + this.props.user.Username + '/followers'}} component={Followers} />
```

And this resulted in the followers component being rendered on what should be /:username and the blank page rendering on /:username/followers.

Any idea's as to why this process doesn't work with my profile component but works fine with settings component?

Edit** A third alternative I tried was to put the match.params into the pathname. Eg.

```
<Route path={{ pathname: this.props.match.params.username }} component={Timeline} />
<Route path={{ pathname: this.props.match.params.username + '/followers' }} component={Followers} />
```

This gave me a similar result as one prior.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `<Route path="/:username" exact component={Timeline} />` will match more routes than you assume.

E.g., it'll match:

```
/about    // username = about
/followers // username = followers
```

and so on. You'd need to make it more specific or declare it as the last route.